# Prototype's Effect.Parallel equivalent in jQuery

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, scriptaculous, jquery-effects

I am trying to convert a Prototype slide-show plugin to jQuery. The animation function is fairly simple an intuitive: fade-out visible slide, fade-in next slide, both animations start and stop at the same time. Here is the Prototype code which I have yet to fully understand:

```
fadeInOut: function (a, b) {
    new Effect.Parallel(
        [
            new Effect.Fade(b, {sync: true}),
            new Effect.Appear(a, {sync: true})
        ], {
            duration: 1
        }
    );
}
```

I've written this jQuery equivalent:

```
var anim = function (a, b) {
    // m_Locked = true
    a.fadeOut(1000);
    b.fadeIn(1000);
    // m_Locked = false
};
```

I am wondering what does Effect.Parallel do and if there is a jQuery equivalent. I also need to set and clear a locked flag which i'll use to disable buttons while the animation is running... this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're interested in `jQuery.queue()`.

> Every element can have one to many
>   queues of functions attached to it by
>   jQuery. In most applications, only one
>   queue (called fx) is used. Queues
>   allow a sequence of actions to be
>   called on an element asynchronously,
>   without halting program execution. The
>   typical example of this is calling
>   multiple animation methods on an
>   element. For example:

http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Comment: Hmm, how can I add an animation to each of the two elements and put them together inside one queue?